# Is there a package that will run monte-carlo cross validation in python?

Tags: python, cross-validation, montecarlo

I am looking for a python package that supports Monte Carlo Cross Validation (Repeated random sub-sampling validation). SkLearn has k-fold, but this will not allow me to specify the ratio of training/testing.

I have seen a package in R that will supposedly achieve this (Caret), but is there an equivalent for python?

Comment: You can split dataset using sklearn's cross_validate. Refer: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package you're after is in fact available in Scikit learn, but is called [ShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit).

Check also the [user guide here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation), where the function is referred to as *Random permutations cross-validation*.